# Why isn't a named rvalue reference turned to const lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

I'm wondering why, in the following example, the function `func` has this signature:

`void func<int&>(int&)`

I know that named rvalue references are treated like lvalue references. I'm wondering why they aren't const lvalue references? I was expecting to see `void func<const int&>(const int&)` as a signature of `func` function.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& t) {}

int main()
{
    int&& t = 5;
    func(t);
}
```

Comment: `t` in `func` is a forwarding reference.  It is being given an lvalue `t` from `main`, so it is resolved as an lvalue reference.  If it were given an rvalue instead, it would resolve as an rvalue reference instead.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But why aren't they const? Does that mean I can change the value of `t`? It turns out I can. That's weird

Comment: The input variable is not `const`, so the reference in `func` is not `const`. So yes, `func` can change the value of the variable that `t` refers to (it cannot change the value of `t` itself, since references can't be rebound)

Comment: I can change it even in `main`. And that's weird since it was initialized with a constant value

Comment: `5` is a const literal, but `int&&` is a reference to a non-const `int`.  The compiler creates a temporary `int` in memory with the value of `5` and then binds the reference to that temporary.

Comment: but if that's temporary shouldn't it always be bound to `const int&` or be moved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251015/discussion-between-erik-nouroyan-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: @ErikNouroyan rvalue-references can cause lifetime extension just like `const` lvalue-references.

Comment: I see. Thank you all for your answers.